# [Homework Question][Finished] about Conjunctive normal form(CNF)

Tags: math, discrete-mathematics

It's a homework question. Can we consider the following as a CNF?

```
(¬x ∧ y) ∧ (x ∨ z)
```

I thinks it's a CNF just like `A ∧ B`, but my friend doesn't agree with me.

Comment: What do you think and why? What's the definition of CNF? Does the formula satisfy it?

Comment: I think it is a CNF, but my friend don't agree with me.

Comment: If you believe that this is a CNF, write your proof here (in the question). Be **extremely** precise. We will either confirm it or tell you where you made a mistake.

Comment: I have tried to explain why, but maybe not that specific due to it's not a really complex question. I'm sorry if this problem make you feel uncomfortable.

Comment: `maybe not that specific due to it's not a really complex question` This is exactly the problem. You believe that this level of explanation of fine, and now you and your friend can't convince each other (since you don't have any precise arguments). If you write everything formally (namely, with *math*), there will be no need for convincing: either your proof contains a mistake (and he has to point it out) or not.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not directly related to programming, it's too broad and a homework question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunctive_normal_form

```
(¬x ∧ y) ∧ (x ∨ z)
```

itself is not strictly a CNF, which requires a disjunction of conjunctive clauses.

It is however equivalent to the following, according to the associative rule ( `(a ∧ b) ∧ c` is equivalent to `a ∧ b ∧ c` ).

```
¬x ∧ y ∧ (x ∨ z)
```

And that can be considered CNF, as being a disjunction of cunjunctive clauses, two of which only contain a single literal, one of which is negated.
Note that CNF does NOT require each conjunctive clause to contain ALL literals.

So in short: Strictly it is not, practically it only requires dropping redundant `()`.

Comment: While I know that anonymous downvotes are part of the game, I invite the downvoter to give reasons.

Comment: I’m not sure why the downvotes either. I think that this is bringing up a valid point.